# Append a variable to a list in python

Tags: python, list, random

here `my_list` is a list containing string(alphabets). i have to select (no. user input) of alphabets randomly. 
my task is to add these (no. user input) to a list and then do a little bit further operation with that list.
my problem here is I am unable to add `rndm` to my `checklist` .

here is m function

```
for i in range(0, n_subs):    
    rndm=my_list[random.randint(0, n_subs)]
    checklist.insert(rndm)
print checklist#check
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Did you mean `checklist.append(rndm)`?

Comment: or perhaps `checklist.insert(0,rndm)`

Comment: you can always get help by typing `help(checklist.insert)` (assuming you want to insert and not append)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`append` function](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to append values to the end of a list.

So instead of doing `checklist.insert(rndm)`, do `checklist.append(rndm)`.

In case you want to insert values at specific location, use  `checklist.insert(i, rndm)`, where `i` is the index of the element before which you want to insert.

Answer (score 3):

`insert()` needs two parameters - index and object.

If you want to append to the end of the list, just use `append()`.